# Chrome maximized window bug Xubuntu (Xfce)

Tags: xubuntu, google-chrome, xfce, maximized

Since last Google-Chrome update to version 95.0.4638.54, Chrome is not respecting screeen size when maximizing the window.

[image: screenshot with google-chrome maxmized]

Comment: I have the same issue... XUbuntu 21.04 Kernel: 5.11.0-38-generic and chrome version is:  95.0.4638.54 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: If it's a bug, have you reported it?  It's not a Ubuntu program (but 3rd party), so it *likely* should be reported with the chromium project - https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list  (it would have to be occurring on other Ubuntu applications for it to be a Xfce/Xubuntu issue in my opinion)

Comment: This is fixed for me in Chrome Version 96.0.4664.45 (Official Build) (64-bit)
 on Linux Mint.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's been identified as a bug in Chrome. The bug that seems the most active is https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1260821

But there are also what appears to be a few duplicates:

- https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1257119
- https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1261797
- https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1264432

Your best bet is to wait for the next Chrome update.

Answer (score 11):

I had the same issue and the solution to it was to "Use system title bar and borders" under the settings on the "System Menu" on the upper-right hand corner in Chrome.

Navigate to settings -> appearance and the setting is in there.

As shown in this picture:[image]

Comment: Basicly this is my answer. You can also find the setting by searching by its name in settings.

Comment: While this does work, it actually removes the minimize/mazimize/close buttons, leaving you with only a new tab "+" and the tab list dropdown down arrow. To change the window size, you have to use right-click on the task bar or double-click on the window header. 

However, *toggling* this setting does temporarily resolve the problem: if you've maximized Chrome, and it doesn't fit, toggle this setting on and back off and the window will resize correctly (until you minimize it again, of course).

Answer (score 2):

I have a workaround for this: enable "Use system title bar and borders" in settings of Google Chrome. (You can search the setting by the name.)

Answer (score 2):

Previous version of chrome did not have such a problem. This is a bug of chrome and I already reported my instances to google. I believe a newer version will fix this soon.

Comment: Link to bug report?

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is observed in the Chrome 95 and higher (unfortunately, the same happens in Chrome Beta 96. at least for me.)
As a workaround I downgraded the Chrome version to 94.
If you have the same problem you can use this workaround:

1. uninstall the `google-chrome-stable` package:
   `sudo apt remove google-chrome-stable`
2. download [Chrome 94](https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/pool/main/g/google-chrome-stable/google-chrome-stable_94.0.4606.81-1_amd64.deb) from Google repository and install it.
3. hold the `google-chrome-stable` package to prevent its updating:
   `sudo apt-mark hold google-chrome-stable`

You will still receive Chrome update lists and see a new version for the package:

```
/$ apt list --upgradable 
Listing... Done
code-insiders/stable 1.63.0-1636719582 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.63.0-1636472235]
code/stable 1.62.2-1636665017 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.62.1-1636111026]
google-chrome-stable/stable 95.0.4638.69-1 amd64 [upgradable from: 94.0.4606.81-1]
```

but it won't install by `sudo apt upgrade`:

```
/$ sudo apt upgrade 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  google-chrome-stable
The following packages will be upgraded:
  code code-insiders
2 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get 163 MB of archives.
After this operation, 26,6 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

until you unhold the `google-chrome-stable` package:
`sudo apt-mark unhold google-chrome-stable`

Answer (score 0):

For those offering up "Use system title bar and borders" as a solution, be aware that this seems to remove the *Minimize*, *Maximize* and *Close* buttons from the title bar, i.e. you'll move from this:

[image: Chrome/XFCE title bar using default settings]

... to this:

[image: Chrome/XFCE title bar using system settings]

(Yes, that's the top-right edge of the window in both images).

You can still manipulate the window by double-clicking on the title bar, of course, along with right-clicking the Chrome tile on the window buttons (i.e. where you get the list of running applications alongside the main Whisker menu button).

You can always take the nuclear option of closing Chrome and then re-opening it, but a more convenient workaround appears to be to simply right-click an item in that main panel (Panel 0 - so, the Whisker Menu, Window Buttons, Workspace Switcher, Notification Area...) , and select "Panel Preferences". Chrome will immediately resize correctly, and then you just close the resultant Preferences dialog.

Note that this doesn't work if you try anything other than Panel 0.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that reloading the xfce panel temporarily resolves this. I did a keybind of "xfce4-panel -r" to an F-key. This will get you by until the Chrome bug is fixed.